# Как из списка сделать HashSet

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список который содержит некоторые данные

```
hello:привет
hello:здрасти
hello:здорова
game:игра
game:развлечение

...
```

Хочу сделать чтобы получился или список, или хешсет который будет содержать данные в таком виде

```
hello:привет,здрасти,здорова
game:игра,развлечение
```

На текущий момент я вижу решение в том чтобы пробежаться по списку, делать `split`, внедрять дополнительный буферный список и т.д... Слишком много движений.

Как с помощью linq сделать это более изящнее?

Comment: Вам нужны в конечном итоге строки, или структура данных?

Comment: И что в вашем списке? Строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, подойдёт такое:

```
// ввод
var lines = new[]
{
    "hello:привет", "hello:здрасти", "hello:здорова", "game:игра", "game:развлечение"
};

// обработка
var pairs = lines.Select(l => l.Split(':'));
var lookup = pairs.ToLookup(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
var combinedLines = lookup.Select(g => g.Key + ":" + string.Join(",", g));

// вывод
foreach (var line in combinedLines)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Результат:

```
hello:привет,здрасти,здорова
game:игра,развлечение
```